# Round down a number in java

Tags: java

I would like to know how I can instruct Java to always round down a given number.

e.g.:

```
1.08 rounds to 1
1.56 rounds to 1
1.67 rounds to 1
1.98 rounds to 2
1.89 rounds to 2
```

I want them rounded to `1` or `2` according to a custom threshold I will provide.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Math.round()?  ..

Comment: You say "*always round down*", and then round `1.89 to 2` ?

Comment: @Eran, see if i use math.round(1.56), the ans will be "2" but i need as "1". Only the above case i asked the suggestion.

Comment: @Rajasekaran how does `1.56 rounds to 1`, and `1.89 rounds to 2` ?

Comment: @ChandlerBing , If i use math.round(1.98) it should be "2" is correct. But if i used math.round(1.67) or (1.56) or (1.6888) it should be "1". This is for my requirement.

Comment: @ChandlerBing , I know chandler but I asked any option like that??

Comment: @Rajasekaran what's the criteria ? Like if decimal part is `>0.8` then round up, or else round down ? Is that it ?

Comment: @ChandlerBing if decimal point >12.8 it should be round down. That's it

Comment: @Rajasekaran What do you mean with " if decimal point >12.8"? That does not make much sense.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. What is your _custom threshold_? Is it like x.8 or is it 1.8? And what should the result look like if the threshold is 1.8 and your number is e.g. 2.82?

Answer (score 5):

Type cast to Integer to avoid fraction value

```
 int roundedNumber = (int) 1.89;
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is not very clear, there are an unlimited number of possible solutions, here are two of them:

```
public class WeirdQuestion {

    // Assuming 0<=threshold<=1
    public static double ThresholdRoundMethodOne(double value, double threshold) {
        return Math.round(value-(1.0-threshold));
    }

    // No limitations for threshold
    public static double ThresholdRoundMethodTwo(double value, double threshold) {
        threshold = threshold-(int)threshold;
        return Math.round(value-(1.0-threshold));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double threshold = 0.8;
        System.out.println("MethodOne: 1.08: "+ThresholdRoundMethodOne(1.08, threshold));
        System.out.println("MethodOne: 1.56: "+ThresholdRoundMethodOne(1.56, threshold));
        System.out.println("MethodOne: 1.67: "+ThresholdRoundMethodOne(1.67, threshold));
        System.out.println("MethodOne: 1.98: "+ThresholdRoundMethodOne(1.98, threshold));
        System.out.println("MethodOne: 1.89: "+ThresholdRoundMethodOne(1.89, threshold));
        System.out.println("MethodOne: 1.8 : "+ThresholdRoundMethodOne(1.8, threshold));
        threshold = 1.8;
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("MethodTwo: 1.08: "+ThresholdRoundMethodTwo(1.08, threshold));
        System.out.println("MethodTwo: 1.56: "+ThresholdRoundMethodTwo(1.56, threshold));
        System.out.println("MethodTwo: 1.67: "+ThresholdRoundMethodTwo(1.67, threshold));
        System.out.println("MethodTwo: 1.98: "+ThresholdRoundMethodTwo(1.98, threshold));
        System.out.println("MethodTwo: 1.89: "+ThresholdRoundMethodTwo(1.89, threshold));
        System.out.println("MethodTwo: 1.8 : "+ThresholdRoundMethodTwo(1.8, threshold));
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigDecimal`, they have a set of rounding method.

Use a `MathContext` object to set the Rounding and the precision:

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.DOWN);
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(1.08, mc);
```

Here is the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: Here the docs for RoundingMode: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Comment: Thanks @Jerome i was posting the reference to the documentation when you post the comment

Answer (score 0):

For rounding down you can use a function like this:

```
int roundDown(double number, double decimals) {

    double result = number;

    // either it rounds it to the upmost number if it is above the threshold
    if (number - (int)number > decimals) {

        result = Math.ceil(result);
    }

    // or it just cuts of the end decimal places
    return (int)result;
}
```

Then you can call it with this, where `YOURDECIMAL` is a `double` that represents the threshold (above it round up, below it rounds down):

```
int myNumber = roundDown(YOURNUMBER, YOURDECIMAL);
```